# CM MotionActivity background event trigger

Tags: ios, iphone, events, background, core-motion

I’ve seen the video on WWDC 2015 Session 705 and found interesting about the Core Motion API. I am making an app that requires update as Motion Activity State changes in the background. For example when the user walked into a car and starts driving, an event will be triggered to notify the app the change of motion activity state.

Do you know any API that keeps track of Motion Activity change and wake the application when necessary? If not, what other choices do I have to accomplish this task?

Thank you very much, and I appreciate any help you give.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you want to do anything with `CMMotionManager` running in the background, as the battery drain will be considerable (and standard background operation is only good for 3 minutes, anyway).

Solutions that would be more respectful of the user's battery include the Core Location's [significant change service](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH2-SW8) or [region monitoring](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/RegionMonitoring/RegionMonitoring.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH9-SW1). Neither is anywhere as sensitive as Core Motion (you may have to travel a few km before app is informed of the change of state!). But these are the preferred methods to balance between the device battery and the app's desire to be informed of a change in location.